# Jhipster blog project sign in failed

Tags: jhipster

I tried to create a jhipster project (**blog**) which is given in the below mentioned youtube url:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XRREt1KB4Y8

When I ran the '**blog**' application and tried to sign in I got below error:

POST http://localhost:9000/api/authenticate 404 (Not Found) Zone.js:1805

[image]

I think server not able to find Zone.js, but I can see this file in below dir:

..\blog\node_modules\zone.js

Please let me know if I missed something while build or deployment. If you need more information please add comments.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have started only the frontend server and forgot to start the java backend server with `mvnw` or `gradlew` depending on which build tool you chose. This is why you get errors 404 for each API calls.

See [documentation](https://jhipster.github.io/development/#running-java-server) for more details